# fixing/recovering JFS superblocks (or recover data from damaged filesystem)

Tags: data-recovery, fsck, jfs

#### Preface:

*Since this is a question about data recovery I expect a lot "non-answers" in the line of "where's your backup?" or "do it on block level image copies". Thanks, I know that, you don't have to lecture me on that. See the notes at the end for what and why. Thank you.*

---

I have a JFS filesystem image that corrupted. *jfs_fsck* refuses to work on it, bailing out with the following error message:

```
~ % sudo jfs_fsck /dev/loop0
jfs_fsck version 1.1.15, 04-Mar-2011
processing started: 3/1/2017 13:08:53
Using default parameter: -p
The current device is:  /dev/loop0
Superblock is corrupt and cannot be repaired 
since both primary and secondary copies are corrupt.  

 CANNOT CONTINUE.
```

Using *jfs_debugfs* commands `su` and `s2p` the folloing information was obtained:

```
~ % sudo  jfs_debug /dev/loop0
jfs_debugfs version 1.1.15, 04-Mar-2011

Aggregate Block Size: 4096
```

**Output of `su p`:**

```
[1] s_magic:            'JFS1'          [15] s_ait2.addr1:      0x00
[2] s_version:          1               [16] s_ait2.addr2:      0x0000e92f
[3] s_size:     0x000000015d4d4ec0           s_ait2.address:    59695
[4] s_bsize:            4096            [17] s_logdev:          0x00000900
[5] s_l2bsize:          12              [18] s_logserial:       0x0009afb1
[6] s_l2bfactor:        3               [19] s_logpxd.len:      8192
[7] s_pbsize:           512             [20] s_logpxd.addr1:    0x00
[8] s_l2pbsize:         9               [21] s_logpxd.addr2:    0x2baa0160
[9] pad:                Not Displayed        s_logpxd.address:  732561760
[10] s_agsize:          0x00800000      [22] s_fsckpxd.len:     22408
[11] s_flag:            0x10200900      [23] s_fsckpxd.addr1:   0x00
                        JFS_LINUX       [24] s_fsckpxd.addr2:   0x2ba9a9d8
        JFS_COMMIT      JFS_GROUPCOMMIT      s_fsckpxd.address: 732539352
                        JFS_INLINELOG   [25] s_time.tv_sec:     0x4902c28b
                                        [26] s_time.tv_nsec:    0x00000000
                                        [27] s_fpack:           'thor_storag'
[12] s_state:           0x00000001
             FM_MOUNT
[13] s_compress:        0
[14] s_ait2.len:        4
```

**Output of `su s`:**

```
[1] s_magic:            '    '          [15] s_ait2.addr1:      0x00
[2] s_version:          0               [16] s_ait2.addr2:      0x00000000
[3] s_size:     0x0000000000000000           s_ait2.address:    0
[4] s_bsize:            0               [17] s_logdev:          0x00000000
[5] s_l2bsize:          0               [18] s_logserial:       0x00000000
[6] s_l2bfactor:        0               [19] s_logpxd.len:      0
[7] s_pbsize:           0               [20] s_logpxd.addr1:    0x00
[8] s_l2pbsize:         0               [21] s_logpxd.addr2:    0x00000000
[9] pad:                Not Displayed        s_logpxd.address:  0
[10] s_agsize:          0x00000000      [22] s_fsckpxd.len:     0
[11] s_flag:            0x00000000      [23] s_fsckpxd.addr1:   0x00
                                        [24] s_fsckpxd.addr2:   0x00000000
                                             s_fsckpxd.address: 0
                                        [25] s_time.tv_sec:     0x00000000
                                        [26] s_time.tv_nsec:    0x00000000
                                        [27] s_fpack:           ''
[12] s_state:           0x00000000
             FM_CLEAN
[13] s_compress:        0
[14] s_ait2.len:        0
```

**Output of `s2p p`:**

```
[1] s_magic:            'JFS1'          [16] s_aim2.len:        2
[2] s_version:          1               [17] s_aim2.addr1:      0x00
[3] s_size:     0x000000015d4d4ec0      [18] s_aim2.addr2:      0x0000e92d
[4] s_bsize:            4096                 s_aim2.address:    59693
[5] s_l2bsize:          12              [19] s_logdev:          0x00000900
[6] s_l2bfactor:        3               [20] s_logserial:       0x0009afb1
[7] s_pbsize:           512             [21] s_logpxd.len:      8192
[8] s_l2pbsize:         9               [22] s_logpxd.addr1:    0x00
[9]  s_agsize:          0x00800000      [23] s_logpxd.addr2:    0x2baa0160
[10] s_flag:            0x10200900           s_logpxd.address:  732561760
             LINUX                      [24] s_fsckpxd.len:     22408
    GROUPCOMMIT                         [25] s_fsckpxd.addr1:   0x00
                INLINELOG               [26] s_fsckpxd.addr2:   0x2ba9a9d8
                                             s_fsckpxd.address: 732539352
[11] s_state:           0x00000001      [27] s_fsckloglen:      50
                MOUNT                   [28] s_fscklog:         2
[12] s_compress:        0               [29] s_fpack:           'thor_storagة�+'
[13] s_ait2.len:        4
[14] s_ait2.addr1:      0x00
[15] s_ait2.addr2:      0x0000e92f
     s_ait2.address:    59695
```

**Output of `s2p s`:**

```
[1] s_magic:            '    '          [16] s_aim2.len:        0
[2] s_version:          0               [17] s_aim2.addr1:      0x00
[3] s_size:     0x0000000000000000      [18] s_aim2.addr2:      0x00000000
[4] s_bsize:            0                    s_aim2.address:    0
[5] s_l2bsize:          0               [19] s_logdev:          0x00000000
[6] s_l2bfactor:        0               [20] s_logserial:       0x00000000
[7] s_pbsize:           0               [21] s_logpxd.len:      0
[8] s_l2pbsize:         0               [22] s_logpxd.addr1:    0x00
[9]  s_agsize:          0x00000000      [23] s_logpxd.addr2:    0x00000000
[10] s_flag:            0x00000000           s_logpxd.address:  0
                                        [24] s_fsckpxd.len:     0
                                        [25] s_fsckpxd.addr1:   0x00
                                        [26] s_fsckpxd.addr2:   0x00000000
                                             s_fsckpxd.address: 0
[11] s_state:           0x00000000      [27] s_fsckloglen:      0
                CLEAN                   [28] s_fscklog:         0
[12] s_compress:        0               [29] s_fpack:           '        '
[13] s_ait2.len:        0
[14] s_ait2.addr1:      0x00
[15] s_ait2.addr2:      0x00000000
     s_ait2.address:    0
```

Now the question is, in what do I have to manipulate in the superblock(s) in which values, so that either *jfs_fsck* can be convinced to go to work, or that I can mount it (using the Linux jfs kernel filesystem implementation)?

It'd be also perfectly acceptable to have some tool that chews through the filesystem image and spits out everything it considers to be a file therein.

---

#### End Notes

Due to events somewhat under my control a Linux mdadm RAID-5 with a JFS filesystem on it got corrupted in a way, which failure mode I still not understand to this day. This FS was part of a NAS I shared with another dude and I repeatedly reminded him, that RAIDs don't replace backups, yet despite these warnings other dude has some non-backuped data on that RAID (*and is now in a stage of being semi-angry… at me I have the impression*). The immediate action was to remove the disks from the system and create block level copies of them. And any kind of manipulation I'm going to do happens on *snapshots* of these copies, so whatever fuckup happens in the recovery process, I can rollback at any time.

Yesterday I was finally able to recover the mdadm RAID into a (hopefully consistent) state.

Basically I want to recover what's there and call it a day.